# How set the current position center on the map?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I tried different approaches which I found on this site and in web but they don't work for me(

This is my code:

```html
<h:panelGroup id="GMWrapper" style="background-color: red">
  <p:gmap widgetVar="mainMap" center="49.835, 24.0083" zoom="15"
          id="mainGoogleMap" type="HYBRID"
          style="width: 600px; height: 400px" model="#{userPlaces.model}"
          styleClass="gmappStyle" onPointClick="handlePointClick(event)" />
  <p:commandButton onclick="someFunc()"></p:commandButton>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function someFunc() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        alert("Start")
        navigator.geolocation
        .getCurrentPosition(success);
        alert("Successful!")
        var elem = document
        .getElementById("mainGoogleMap");
        alert("Element was find")
        elem.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419));
        alert("Good done!");
      } else {
        error('Geo Location is not supported');
        currentLat = 0.0;
        currentLng = 0.0;
      }
    }

    var currentLat;
    var currentLng;

    function success(position) {
      currentLat = position.coords.latitude;
      currentLng = position.coords.longitude;
    }
  </script>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Javascript code works to `alert("Element was find")`

Also I tried:

`elem.setAttribute("center", currentLat.toString() + ", " + currentLng.toString());
elem.setAttribute("center", currentLat + ", " + currentLng);
elem.setAttribute("center", "37.4419, -122.1419");`
and few other..

Comment: Did you try just centering the element with CSS ?

Comment: @adeneo Set Google Map center with CSS???
I don't known how do that.

Comment: I think you mean set the current map position centre to the map??

Comment: So are you trying to center the map on a latitude and longitude, or center the element in the browser. You're setting a `center` attribute on an element, hence the confusion ?

Comment: @gerdi Yes, I do. I already changed question

Comment: @adeneo to center the map on a latitude and longitude

Comment: Well, first you create a map, lets call it `myMap` and you do that with `new google.maps` etc. ***Then*** you set the position with `myMap.setCenter(new LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419));`, right now you're calling `setCenter` on the document for some strange reason ?

Comment: @adeneo if I create new map, how should I associate `myMap` with already existing map (`p:gmap` element)?

Answer (score 0):

From the google maps docs: panTo(latLng:LatLng|LatLngLiteral) - Changes the center of the map to the given LatLng. If the change is less than both the width and height of the map, the transition will be smoothly animated. Below is a snippet that creates a map and centers the map at a location.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
  map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419));
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```